# XSD namespace "ns2" issue

Tags: xsd

I have schema defined in Request.xsd which will refer common.xsd.
I'm expecting the output should come as below

```
<Request xmlns="http://ws.myref.com/schemas/test" 
        xmlns="http://ps.myref.com/schemas/2008/Common">
 <EmailList>
     <Mail>test@gmail.com</Mmail>
  </EmailList>
</Request>
```

But i'm getting extra namespace "ns2" issue. Can anybody help me out to resolve this issue

```
<ns2:Request xmlns:ns2="http://ps.myref.com/schemas/test" 
             xmlns="http://ps.myref.com/schemas/Common">
    <ns2:EmailList>
       <Mail>test@gmail.com</Mail>
    </ns2:EmailList>
</ns2:Request>
```

Request.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ps.myref.com/schemas/schemas/test"
            xmlns="http://ps.myref.com/schemas/schemas/test" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
            xmlns:com="http://ps.myref.com/schemas/Common">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://ps.myref.com/schemas/Common" schemaLocation="../schemas/common/common.xsd"/>
    <xsd:element name="Request">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="EmailLists" type="com:EmailList" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Common.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://ps.myref.com/schemas/2008/Common" elementFormDefault="unqualified"
            targetNamespace="http://ps.myref.com/schemas/Common"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsd:complexType name="EmailList">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Mail" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectation is unreasonable in this instance.

Because the type "EmailList" is defined under the namespace `http://ps.myref.com/schemas/2008/Common` in the common.xsd file, you have no option but to differentiate it in some way when you use the EmailList type in another schema. If you look at request.xsd, you can see that this is exectyly what happens here:

```
<xsd:element name="EmailLists" type="com:EmailList" />
```

The `com:` in this case is a prefix designed to show that the type is defined in another schema and under a different namespace to the one being used.

In the same way, when the xsd validator uses the request.xsd to validate a schema instance, it has to ensure that the EmailList type you are using in your instance is the same EmailList type which is defined in the common.xsd schema, and the only way it can do that is by using the namespace.

Your expectation can therefore be summarized thus:

"I should be able to mix types defined in two different schema definitions freely together without differentiating them and the parser should understand that."

So you should be able to see now how your expectation does not make logical sense.

If you don't want the "ns2:" in there, your only other alternative is to do this:

```
<Request xmlns"http://ps.myref.com/schemas/test">
    <EmailList xmlns"http://ps.myref.com/schemas/test">
       <Mail xmlns="http://ps.myref.com/schemas/Common">test@gmail.com</Mail>
    </EmailList>
</Request>
```